# How to do a widget in Qt that expands above his layout

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt4

How would you do a widget in Qt that expands above his layout without affecting it and not being a dialog.

My idea is to be like in word 2007 :
 - Collapsed : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yp90t.png
 - Expanded : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0nNE.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second one is actually a popup widget. You get what I mean? When the user press a expand button. Create a popup widget in that position.

Comment: And note that a popup widget is not a dialog! It will not block the main application from functioning.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to be done that way.

Instead I'd implement it using a borderless window that will be placed above the widget that initially caused the "dropdown" to show. This way you also solve issues where the dropdown would have to overlap the window borders as well. Just hide it once it loses